# Setting default value of <select> element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in my webpage that captures the details of a previous order history. The table has the following columns:

Order    Date     Review

Now, for the review, I want to have a select dropdown with some options. When user first launches the page, I want the previous rating to show up as default in the select dropdown. Here is what my code looks like:

```
tds.push( {
    content: '<select id="clientReview" name="clientReview" value=' + obj.get("client_review") + '>' +
    '<option value=1>Hate it!</option>' +
    '<option value=2>Don't love it but don't hate it.</option>' +
    '<option value=3>Fantastic!</option>' 
});
```

I was expecting that setting the value in **select** would set the default value in the dropdown but that's not happening. I still see the first value as default. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: imho, you are missing `\'` for option 2.

Comment: Use DOM nodes in JavaScript, not strings (that's kinda what JavaScript was **made** to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What about setting of value after inserting of HTML to document?

   **HTML:**

   ```
   <select id="dropdown">
       <option value="1">One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option value="3">Three</option>
   </select>
   <input id="textField" type="text" value="2" />
   ```

   **JavaScript:**

   ```
   (function() {
       var dropdown$ = $('#dropdown'),
           textField$ = $('#textField');

       function changeVal() {
           var val = parseInt(textField$.val());
           if(!!val && val > 0 && val < 4) {
               dropdown$.val(val);
           }
       }

       textField$.on('keyup', changeVal);

       changeVal();
   })();​
   ```

   **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/hwGx3/)**
2. `<option value="1" selected="selected">Text</option>`

   See:
    http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option#HTML_Attributes
    http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp
3. Based on your code example I can assume that you'll use this HTML to insert somewhere later. In this case you can have something like next code:

   ```
   tds.push( {
       content: '<select id="clientReview" name="clientReview" data-value="' + obj.get("client_review") + '">' +
       '<option value="1" >Hate it!</option>' +
       '<option value="2" >Don\'t love it but don\'t hate it.</option>' +
       '<option value="3" >Fantastic!</option>' +
       '</select>'
   });​

   function insertDropdown(td$, dropdownHTML) {
       var dropdown$ = $(dropdownHTML);
       dropdown$.val(dropdown$.data('value'));
       td$.html(dropdown$);
   }

   for(var i = 0, l = tds.length; i < l; i++) {
       insertDropdown($('#td-' + i), tds[i].content);
   }
   ```

   **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/cYYp9/)**

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future!

Comment: Thanks Matt and Evgeniy! I want to set the default at the same time I am adding the HTML to the document because my table can have a large number of rows and it seemed tedious to have to go through each row and change the defaults. I thought there was an elegant way of doing it. I will try to modify the solution above and see how that works out.

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: OK, thanks, Madara. I've added also a link to w3.org, but this is not changing an idea of particular answer anyway.